# Recode adjacency matrix cells based on conditions from data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, conditional-statements, apply

I have a dataset of adolescents in a number of different schools and grades. My goal is to make an adjacency matrix of all the kids, and add structural zeros (value = 10) for those students in different schools and grades (They were only allowed to nominate friends in the same school and grade as themselves).

So far I have the adjacency matrix, but I'm not sure how to change the cell values based on conditions from the vertex attribute data frame.

Sample dataframe and matrix I have below.

HAVE DF:

```
id  school  grade   friendid_1  friendid_2  friendid_3  friendid_4
 1     101      8            2           4          NA          NA
 2     101      8           NA          NA          NA          NA
 3     101      8            1           5           2          NA
 4     101      8            1          NA           2          NA
 5     101      9            1           3          NA          NA
 6     101      9            9           7          NA          NA
 7     101      9            9          10          NA          NA
 8     101      9           NA          10          NA          NA
 9     101      9            6          NA          NA          NA
10     101      9           NA          NA           7          NA
11     102      8           15          NA          NA          NA
12     102      8           11          15          NA          NA
13     102      9           15          12          14          11
14     102      9           13          NA          NA          NA
15     102      9           12          NA          NA          NA
16     103      8           19          NA          NA          17
17     103      8           19          20          NA          NA
18     103      8           17          NA          NA          NA
19     103      8           NA          NA          NA          17
20     103      8           18          17          19          NA
```

HAVE MATRIX:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
 1  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 2  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 3  1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 4  1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 5  1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 6  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 7  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 8  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 9  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
12  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
13  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
14  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
15  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0
17  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
18  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
19  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
20  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0
```

WANT MATRIX:

```
     1  2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
 1  0   1   0   1   0   10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
 2  0   0   0   0   0   10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
 3  1   1   0   0   1   10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
 4  1   1   0   0   0   10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
 5  1   0   1   0   0   10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
 6  10  10  10  10  10  0   1   0   1   0   10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
 7  10  10  10  10  10  0   0   0   1   1   10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
 8  10  10  10  10  10  0   0   0   0   1   10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
 9  10  10  10  10  10  1   0   0   0   0   10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
10  10  10  10  10  10  0   1   0   0   0   10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
11  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  0   0   0   0   1   10  10  10  10  10
12  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  1   0   0   0   1   10  10  10  10  10
13  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  1   1   0   1   1   10  10  10  10  10
14  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  0   0   1   0   0   10  10  10  10  10
15  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  0   1   0   0   0   10  10  10  10  10
16  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  0   1   0   1   0
17  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  0   0   0   1   1
18  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  0   1   0   0   0
19  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  0   1   0   0   0
20  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  0   1   1   1   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through all persons and use the information of the dataset to change the matrix:

```
## d is your data.frame, m is your matrix
for(i in 1:dim(d)[1]){
  pid = d$id[i]
  m[pid,][d$grade!=d$grade[i] | d$school!=d$school[i]] = 10
  m[,pid][d$grade!=d$grade[i] | d$school!=d$school[i]] = 10
}
```

This will set all cells to `10` that don't satisfy the condition that row and column belong to the same school and grade.

Comment: I'm getting this error: Error in `*tmp*`[pid, ] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: Ah I think what's happening is that dim(d)[1] calls the row numbers, but the row numbers in the real dataset I'm using are non sequential. For example, I have 1497 observations, but the actual row names range from 22-8821

Comment: Yes, I suspected as much. That's why the id of each row (`d$id[i]`) is used instead of the real row number. But if you don't include all the ids in your matrix, that won't work. You could also loop over the `rownames` of the matrix and use them to get the school and grade from the data.frame.

Comment: shifting the id# to rownames and then using that worked! thanks!